# Common place to set custom validators in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring5, spring-validation

We are upgrading our Spring version from 4 to 5.

Validations in the Spring 4 application were implemented by overriding `MultiActionController`'s `bind()` method and setting the list of custom validators based on the bean to validate and the method that was called for processing the request using a common method for all the controller methods in a controller.

How to do the same in Spring 5 where I can set the custom validators list in a common place for all the controller methods?

Comment: have you tried any example? See if this can help you:- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation